# Como modificar um item em um ponto especifico da página? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

Olá, na minha pagina possui um menu fixo composto por texto, preciso que quando ele chegue a certo ponto da pagina ele mude da cor branca para preta mas não tenho ideia de como posso fazer isso.

[image: Site]

Comment: Como definir qual é o "certo ponto"?

Comment: mas quem era branco e deverá ser preto?  Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Postar código como imagem -
 https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: o que seria "certo ponto"? para mudar o estilo de um elemento em JS, usa `elemento.style = "estilo";` é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será que precisa ser somente com CSS mesmo?

Se puder ser com **JavaScript** pode usar o *scroll touchmove* do **jQuery**.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#mudar").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'orange');
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
  }
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div id="mudar">Mudar quando chegar aqui.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
<div>Não muda.</div>
```

> A vantagem dessa função *scroll touchmove* é que você não precisa
>   definir o tamanho da rolagem que vai ser feita para mudar a
>   propriedade do elemento, porque o tamanho da rolagem pode mudar dependendo do
>   dispositivo que está acessando o site. Então o *scroll touchmove* só
>   muda a propriedade quando o topo do navegador chega no elemento
>   escolhido que no caso do meu código foi a `<div>` com o `id="mudar"`.

Aprendi com o cara que respondeu essa pergunta minha: [Mudar aparência ao passar pela section](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232534)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar tanto jQuery como Javascript.

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // Seleciona o elemento alvo
  var element = document.querySelector(".element");
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
    // Ao descer 100px, realiza as modificações desejadas
    element.classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
    // Ao retornar ao topo da página, desfaz as modificações
    element.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    // Ao descer 100px, realiza as modificações desejadas
    $('.element').addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    // Ao retornar ao topo da página, desfaz as modificações
    $('.element').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

---

**Exemplos**

- [JavaScript](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEYJvz)
- [jQuery](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVPNWY)